# Unable to access contents of initialized struct in a map

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, dictionary, multimap

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    Qt::Key qKey;
    QString strFormType;
} KeyPair;
```

Now I initialize KeyPair instantiations so I could use it for my Automated Test App.

```
KeyPair gDial[] =
{
    { Qt::Key_1 , "MyForm" },
    { Qt::Key_1 , "SubForm" },
    { Qt::Key_Escape, "DesktopForm" }
};

KeyPair gIP[] =
{
    { Qt::Key_1 , "MyForm" },
    { Qt::Key_2 , "Dialog" },
    { Qt::Key_2 , "Dialog" },
    { Qt::Key_Escape, "DesktopForm" }
};
....
and like 100 more instantiations....
```

Currently, I call a function which uses these KeyPairs.

```
qDebug() << "Testing Test Menu"; 
pressKeyPairs( gDial);

qDebug() << "Testing Browse Menu"; 
pressKeyPairs( gIP);
....
and more calls like this for the rest...
```

I would like to put all these KeyPair instantiations in a MAP so I wouldn't have to call pressKeyPairs() and qDebug() a hundred times... I'm a newbie in using MAPS... so I tried:

```
map<string,KeyPair> mMasterList;
map<string,KeyPair>::iterator it;   

mMasterList.insert( pair<string, KeyPair>("Testing Test Menu", *gDial) ); //which I know is wrong, but how?
mMasterList.insert( pair<string, KeyPair>("Testing IP Menu", *gIP) );
mMasterList.insert( pair<string, KeyPair>("IP Menu2", *gIP2) );
....

for ( it=mMasterList.begin() ; it != mMasterList.end(); it++ )
{
   qDebug() << (*it).first << endl;
   pressKeyPairs((*it).second);       
   // I don't know how to access .second ... this causes a compiler error
}
```

EDIT: 
pressKeyPairs is declared as:

```
template <size_t nNumOfElements> void pressKeyPairs(KeyPair (&keys)[nNumOfElements]);
```

This code block isn't working... :( Can somebody tell me how to properly put these KeyPairs in a Map?

Comment: That is the definition of `pressKeyPairs` and what is your compile error?

Comment: What's the compiler error you're getting? Also, my guess would be that pressKeyPairs() gets a const KeyPair& but you're using an iterator instead of a const_iterator (as you should probably do anyway, because it's "more correct")

Comment: Compiler error : no matching function for call to `pressKeyPairs(KeyPair&)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Henning's answer is the way to go.
`*gDial` and `*gIP` in your code mean `gDial[0]` and `gIP[0]`.
So, you insert only the first element of the `KeyPair` array into `mMasterList`.

Your `pressKeyPairs`'s declaration
`template<size_t nNumOfElements> void pressKeyPairs(KeyPair(&keys)[nNumOfElements]);`
itself is correct. It takes a reference to `KeyPair` array as an argument.
However, since `mMasterList`'s `second_type` is `KeyPair`(not `KeyPair` array),
`pressKeyPairs((*it).second)` invokes type mismatch error.

How about the following ideas?

- Making a type `KeyPairArray` which
  points to `KeyPair` array
- `pressKeyPairs` takes a reference to
  `KeyPairArray`

For example:

```
struct KeyPairArray {
  size_t nNumOfElements;
  KeyPair *keys;

  template< size_t N >
  KeyPairArray( KeyPair(&k)[ N ] ) : nNumOfElements( N ), keys( k ) {}
};

// Example
void pressKeyPairs( KeyPairArray const& keys )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0;  i < keys.nNumOfElements;  ++ i ) {
    qDebug()<< keys.keys[ i ].qKey <<','<< keys.keys[ i ].strFormType <<'\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  map<string,KeyPairArray> mMasterList;
  map<string,KeyPairArray>::iterator it;
  mMasterList.insert(
    make_pair( "Testing Test Menu", KeyPairArray( gDial ) ) );

  for ( it=mMasterList.begin() ; it != mMasterList.end(); it++ ) {
    pressKeyPairs( it->second );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not that wrong after all. You are getting a compiler error just because the compiler does not know how to output your array of structs to cout, so if you just output (*it).first and iterate over the elements of (*it).second you should be fine. Note however that you somehow need to make sure you know the number of entries in each of such arrays. That can be achieved for example by always having some kind of null entry as the last one (or a convention that the escape key is always the last entry or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(KeyPair)** after your typedef declaration and also call **qRegisterMetaType("KeyPair");** before using **KeyPair** struct instances.

Comment: You don't need that to put something into a QMap.